# Showing the correct item in a master Combobox coupled with a BindingNavigator in a master/detail relationship

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, sql-server-ce

There are a lot of questions similar to mine but my problem is in the inverse of the typical question: I am unable to get the items in a master Combobox shows up correctly when moving along the detail recordset. I am quite new to Ado.Net so, please, expect some mess: my knowledge about the ADO.NET data object model is still poor; anyways this is my code:

```
     private DataSet MainDataSet           = new DataSet("MainDataSet");     
     BindingSource DetailBindingDataSource = new BindingSource();
     BindingSource MasterBindingDataSource = new BindingSource();

     SqlCeDataAdapter MasterDataAdapter;
     SqlCeDataAdapter DetailDataAdapter;
     MainDataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;

     MasterDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(GET_MASTERS_SQL_COMMAND, CONNECTION_STRING);
     DetailDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(GET_DETAILS_SQL_COMMAND, CONNECTION_STRING);

     GetData(MainDataSet, ImagesDataAdapter, "masters");       // just a wrapper
     GetData(MainDataSet, DefectsDataAdapter, "details");     // just a wrapper

     DataTable DetailTable = MainDataSet.Tables["details"];
     DataTable MasterTable = MainDataSet.Tables["masters"];           
     DetailBindingDataSource.DataSource = DetailTable;
     MasterBindingDataSource.DataSource = MasterTable;

// establishing relationships between Master / Detail data 
// to keep in sync related comboboxes with BindingNavigator

     DataRelation DetailHasMaster = new DataRelation("DetailHasMaster", MainDataSet.Tables["masters"].Columns["master"], MainDataSet.Tables["details"].Columns["details"]);
     MainDataSet.Relations.Add(DetailHasMaster);

     BindingNavigator SearchNavigator      = new BindingNavigator(true);
     SearchNavigator.BindingSource         = DetailBindingDataSource;    

     // Just as example, binding some fields: this is working, data change when moving on with BindingNavigator
     DataTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", DetailBindingDataSource, "creationDate"));
     ItemTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", DetailBindingDataSource, "partnumber"));
     SerialNumTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", DetailBindingDataSource, "SerialNumber"));
     NoteTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", DetailBindingDataSource, "note"));

/*
 * Assign data origin to the binding sources; 
 * this is NOT working, the master combobox do not changes when moving 
 * on with BindingNavigator
 */    
     MasterComboBox.DataSource = MasterBindingDataSource;
     MasterComboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
     MasterComboBox.ValueMember = "master";  

     private void GetData(DataSet CurrentDataSet, 
                          SqlCeDataAdapter CurrentDataAdapter, 
                          String TableName)
     {
          CurrentDataAdapter.FillSchema(CurrentDataSet, SchemaType.Source, TableName);
          CurrentDataAdapter.Fill(CurrentDataSet, TableName);
          SqlCeCommandBuilder GenericCommandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(CurrentDataAdapter);
          CurrentDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = GenericCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
          CurrentDataAdapter.InsertCommand = GenericCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();         
     }
```

Have someone pointers to the right solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a proper solution: my idea was that the combobox could be updated automatically by means of some property or method of the involved objects. The quick and dirty solution I have implemented is:

1. Subscribe the BindingSource.CurrentChanged event to be notified about stepping along the data
2. Check for:  if (BindingSource.Count == 0)
3. Update manually the ComboBox.SelectedValue with values from the current row.

I believe that a better and more ADO capabilities - aware must exists, but this anyway saved my Sunday.